# Recibir query por url GOLANG

Tags: mongodb, sql, url, go

Estoy incursionando con golang para el desarrollo de un servidor de backend, con mongodb, y no logro recibir los parametros por url para la ejecucion de las querys
¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: Estás usando algún framework en concreto como Beego por ejemplo?

Comment: estoy usando gorilla/mus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes el router definido de esta manera:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
```

y que tienes por ejemplo un ruta registrada para usuarios con su id como parametro

```
r.HandleFunc("/users/{id}", myHandler.GetUserHandler).Methods("GET")
```

en tu función que recibe esa url:

```
func GetUserHandler(writer http.ResponseWriter, r *http.request) {
    parametros := mux.Vars(r)
    id := parametros["id"]
    fmt.Println(id)
}
```

De esta manera obtendrias la id de tu url que seria por ejemplo: /users/5

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
Si bien esa estructrua me sirve para un path statico lo que estoy buscando es resolverlo por un path variable (asi puedo filtrar o borrar por algun dato que tengan mis objetos demongo)